# Use query value in same query

Tags: mysql, sql

If I have one query with two selects, can I use a value from the first select in the second select?

i.e:

```
(SELECT post_id AS post_1 FROM posts WHERE user_id = 100) UNION (SELECT post_id AS post_2 FROM posts WHERE user_id = post_1)
```

The above doesn't work, so how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what your trying to do, you can use a sub-query to get the results for your `WHERE` clause

For example

```
SELECT post_id AS post_2 FROM posts
WHERE user_id = (SELECT post_id AS post_1 FROM posts WHERE user_id = 100)
```

Or you can run the two queries in sequence assigning the first result to a variable and using that

For example

```
SET myVar = (SELECT post_id AS post_1 FROM posts WHERE user_id = 100);

SELECT post_id AS post_2 FROM posts WHERE user_id = myVar
```

Comment: That would only return the result of one of those queries. I need to be able to return the separate results of both queries.

Comment: OK I think I misunderstood what you are trying to do, in that case you probably want to do a self join like Hartmut suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're looking for a join?

```
SELECT p1.post_id as post_id1
     , p2.post_id as post_id2
  FROM posts p1
  JOIN posts p2
    ON p2.user_id = p1.post_id
 WHERE p1.user_id = 100;
```